There is a div.main having blue borders containing CAFINA heading h1, WE SERVE heading h2 just above the footer. How to make it occupy whole page?
There is a div.main having blue borders containing CAFINA heading h1, WE SERVE heading h2 just above the footer. Why is it occupying a vertical box instead of the whole screen. Its looking rubbish. I tried increasing the division width but it is not happening
I tried increasing the width but nothing is changing on the preview. i was expecting the whole main division to occupy the complete space it has

Can you provide your css and html stuff?

Pls share your code
